# How to open a new frame/window with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

When "Create node" button is clicked, how can I open a new frame or window? I want the new frame to contain a text field and dropdown menu so that user can select an option.

```
<form>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Create node</button><br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Search node</button><br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Create Realationship</button><br>
</body>
</html>
</form>
```

From the code above, I'm able to create and click the buttons but I'm unable to create a new frame and I don't know how to give options for the user to select.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already

Comment: i would like to know how to open a frame or window and add some buttons and text field.. i have tried til creating a button and clicking it but unable to do next options...

Comment: Is it proper to place a form outside of the `<html>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   //create some html elements with the createElement function
    var select = document.createElement("select"),
        input = document.createElement("input");
    var head = document.createElement("h2");
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");

    //change the content of elements
    head.innerHTML = "select and edit option";

    option1.innerHTML = "option 1";
    option2.innerHTML = "option 2";
    //you can add an element to another element with element.appendChild("new child element here")

    select.appendChild(option1);
    select.appendChild(option2);

    //you can set all attributes with element.setAttribute("attribute name", "attribute value")
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");

    //open a window, with no url and a specified width and height
    var w = window.open('', "", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");

    //again add children elements, but now insert them to the created window which is stored in the 'w' variable (note that it does not replaces the document, it only means that you represent another window)
    w.document.body.appendChild(head);
    w.document.body.appendChild(select);
    w.document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkf4cnqo/5/

you can also load a predefined url but than it would be difficult to make it dynamic.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: tanks sake, this opens a new window.. now how do i add some text box and drop down in the new window

Comment: It already creates a text box and a drop down menu (see fiddle demo)

Comment: i have 3 buttons 
1.Create node 
          I have your code here
2.Create Relation
3.Search Relation
        But in this if i click any button, then the same code runs .. how do i filter the code as per the button clicked

Comment: Since all code is almost the same use an identifier when you call the function f.e. myFunction("1")  and than run the code a little bit different (demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkf4cnqo/10/)

Comment: yes this worked, how can i have more then one drop down and text box in the same new window ?

Answer (score 0):

To start with you're code is not proper. `<form>` should be created in the body and `<html>` should be the first tag in your document. Next if I understand you correctly you simply want to create a new window after clicking any of the buttons.

You can simply create a function named `myFunction` and pass in `window.open('http://google.com')` to it. You can use any url you want in there so if your website was `http://example.com` you could create a page with the buttons and text field at `http://example.com/node1.html` and you would change the `window.open('http://google.com')` to `window.open('http://example.com/node1.html`)`

```
<html>

    <head>

    </head>
<body>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("http://google.com");
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Create Node</button>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this works but i need ,in the new window one drop down with a label(Please select the nodes and options in it) for the user to select and one text box(Please enter the properties) where in the user can input the properties and submit